# Widget not updated when selecting AppEnum with AppIntents

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit, ios17, appintents

I'm trying to select options for a widget using a drop-down, and provide the user with a limited list of options that will never change. I'm using an AppEnum [as recommended](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/making-a-configurable-widget). However, when selecting an element from the back of the widget, the widget doesn't update.

Here's my code:

```swift
import AppIntents
import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit

struct TestProvider: AppIntentTimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> TestEntry {
        TestEntry(date: .now, bool: false, str: "Apple", enum1: TestEnum.test1)
    }
    
    func snapshot(for configuration: TestIntent, in context: Context) async -> TestEntry {
        return TestEntry(date: .now, bool: false, str: "Apple", enum1: TestEnum.test1)
    }
    
    func timeline(for configuration: TestIntent, in context: Context) async -> Timeline<TestEntry> {
        let testBool = configuration.bool
        let testStr = configuration.str

        return Timeline(entries: [
            TestEntry(
                date: .now,
                bool: testBool,
                str: testStr,
                enum1: TestEnum.test1
            )
        ], policy: .atEnd)
    }
}

struct TestEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let bool: Bool
    let str: String
    let enum1: TestEnum
}

struct TestIntent: AppIntent, WidgetConfigurationIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Testing"
    static var description: IntentDescription = .init(stringLiteral: "1, 2, 3, testing")

    @Parameter(title: "Test bool")
    var bool: Bool

    @Parameter(title: "Test string", default: "Apple")
    var str: String

    @Parameter(title: "Test enum", default: .test1)
    var enum1: TestEnum
}

struct TestWidgetView: View {
    var entry: TestEntry

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(entry.str)
                .foregroundStyle(entry.bool ? .green : .red)
            Text(entry.enum1 == TestEnum.test1 ? "1" : "2")
            Text(entry.enum1.rawValue)
        }
        .containerBackground(for: .widget) {}
    }
}

struct testWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "Test Widget"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        AppIntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: TestIntent.self, provider: TestProvider()) { entry in
            TestWidgetView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Test widget")
        .description("Just a test")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall])
    }
}

enum TestEnum: String, AppEnum {
    static var typeDisplayRepresentation: TypeDisplayRepresentation = "Test title 1"

    case test1 = "1"
    case test2 = "2"

    static var caseDisplayRepresentations: [TestEnum : DisplayRepresentation] = [
        .test1: "test 1",
        .test2: "test 2"
    ]
}

#Preview(as: .systemSmall) {
    testWidget()
} timeline: {
    TestEntry(date: .now, bool: false, str: "Apple", enum1: TestEnum.test1)
}
```

It's a barebones example. The widget updates correctly if I change the boolean or the string, but not if I change the enum selection.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the selected value using the given configuration in timeLine().

```swift
func timeline(for configuration: TestIntent, in context: Context) async -> Timeline<TestEntry> {
        let testBool = configuration.bool
        let testStr = configuration.str

        return Timeline(entries: [
            TestEntry(
                date: .now,
                bool: testBool,
                str: testStr,
                enum1: configuration. enum1 //<= here
            )
        ], policy: .atEnd)
    }
```